How to build and run next js app independently using node server
I am new to Next JS and React JS
I have a simple next js app, i want to build that application which can be done using command
npm run build

which creates a .next folder, now i want to copy that .next folder and run that as an separate application using node server or http server, can this be done ?
I used to work on angular earlier and we were able to do so, with dist folder created after the build

Your question is similar to this

In a word, no. Next has it's own webserver as part of the meta-framework. If you want to run your own web server then make a vanilla React app and don't use next. Next is closer to something like Angular Universe than just plain Angular. It is technically possible to do what you're asking, but it probably isn't what you should be doing as a beginner and negates a lot of the value of using next.
